# C# установка нескольких иконок разного размера

Tags: c#, icon

Программа работает в windows tray. Хочу установить несколько иконок для программы разных размеров. Для трея 16px, для windows панели 48px.

Если собираю несколько изображений (16px и 48px) в один ico файл, то в трей подставляется изображение в 48px, что смотрится неестественно.

На PyQT я бы мог сделать так:

```
app_icon = QIcon()
app_icon.addFile('ico/ico_16.png', QSize(16, 16))
app_icon.addFile('ico/ico_24.png', QSize(24, 24))
app_icon.addFile('ico/ico_32.png', QSize(32, 32))
app_icon.addFile('ico/ico_48.png', QSize(48, 48))
app_icon.addFile('ico/ico_48.png', QSize(256, 256))
d.setWindowIcon(app_icon)
```

Как в C# я могу явно указать, что для трея необходимо использовать иконку с 16px?

Сейчас иконку устанавливаю так:

```
this.Icon = new Icon("img/cloud_ico.ico");
```

Comment: попробуй собрать изображения в один файл с размерами 16х16, 32x32, 48x48 и 256x256. Именно такие размеры.

Comment: А чем вы собираете изображения в одно?

Comment: Фокус с размерами не прошел. Иконка в окно подставляется нужная, а в трей по-прежнему большая. Собираю с помощью утилиты - https://icoconvert.com/Multi_Image_to_one_icon/